# Why does it show an error while declaring a variable in BASIC?

Tags: var, basic

I am using the BASIC programming language and while declaring variable;
`dim basic as string`

it shows the error that unexpected token called DIM.
wonder why?

Comment: **Exactly** [which implementation of BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BASIC_dialects) are you using?

Comment: If you are using interpretive BASIC, i.e. GWBASIC, all code lines require a preceding line number, i.e. 10 DIM Basic As String  However, if it is indeed GWBASIC, you don't need to declare variables except for arrays AND generally instead of As String you'd use $ to denote a string, i.e. 10 DIM Basic$

Comment: @Dai its not working still shows unexpected error at line 10 DIM

Comment: @CoopGood Please answer the question I asked you first.